# Tkinter Toplevel() in function called from button's command makes not accessible variables

Tags: python, tkinter

Thank you for reading my post! I'm still newbie in coding and I meet a brick wall.
Let's get to the point, so I try to create a GUI on root window I have a button:

```
add_association_button = Button(text="Add Association Text", image=add_association_icon, command=add_association)
```

When user hit this button another window appears with Entry and save button.

```
def add_association():
    input_window = Toplevel()
    input_window.config(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, padx=10, pady=10)
    input_window.title("Set association")
    association_label = Label(input_window, text=f"Provide association for the word {word_on_the_screen.japanese_word}",
                                                 bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))
    global association_entry
    association_entry = Entry(input_window, width = 50)
    save_button = Button(input_window, text="Save", command=save_association)
    association_label.pack()
    association_entry.pack()
    save_button.pack()
```

And here is the problem with save button, I want to save user's value to global object and close input_window. I figured out that I can use global for association_entry and get it in second instance of function

```
def save_association():
    #TODO
    global association_entry
    user_association = association_entry.get()
    global word_on_the_screen
    word_on_the_screen.association = user_association
    canvas.itemconfig(word_association_canvas, text=word_on_the_screen.association)
```

My question here is how can I close input_window in save_association function and is there any other way getting to association_entry in save_association?

Is it even proper way for implementation or implementation of input_window should be in main_body? If so how to make visible and invisible input_window according to my will? I think that can solve my problems :)

For any answers big Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not clear on first read because if the window is closed, how is the button pressed and `save_association()` get executed. But later I assumed you mean, you want to call `save_association()` somewhere else after the window is closed. Well there is a way I can think of here, when the window is closed, call a function that will get the user entry and make it `global`. So it would be like:

```
from _tkinter import TclError

.....
def add_association():
    input_window = Toplevel()
    .....

    def save():
        global inp # Notice I used inp instead of input because it is built in function
        inp = association_entry.get() # Get the value and make it global
        input_window.destroy() # Close the window

    input_window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',save) # If window is closed execute save()
```

Then your other function would be:

```
def save_association():
    global inp
    #TODO
    try:
        inp = association_entry.get() 
    except TclError: # This error will get triggered if window is closed, by which last typed input from save() will be used
        pass
    word_on_the_screen.association = user_association
    canvas.itemconfig(word_association_canvas, text=inp)
```

As I do not have a working example, I cannot try this code out, but this should do the trick. This is just like a hacky way by overwriting the variables if error occurs else fetching it from the entry box itself.

Comment: Thanks @Cool Cloud